# In pyomo how can one extract the second derivative from the objective function

Tags: python, derivative, pyomo

I'm working with pyomo and already have a model defined, with an objective function to go with it. After the model is solved, the objective function has certain parameters attached to it. So if i had a multi index variable `[x1, x2, x3]`, my quadratic objective function would suppose look something like this: `(x1^2 + 13*x2^2 + 10*x3^2) + (2*x1 +......)` .

My question is: given that i can actually access this expression in string format from the objective, is there any way to obtain the second derivative of this function with respect to all the variables?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways to get derivative information in Pyomo.

If you need numeric derivatives at a single point, you can use a tool like the "gjh_asl_json" tool (https://github.com/ghackebeil/gjh_asl_json) that can take an NL file generated by Pyomo and produces a JSON file with the Jacobian and Hessian information.

If you want symbolic derivatives, Pyomo can provide those directly, provided you also have `sympy` installed:

```
from pyomo.core.base.symbolic import differentiate
from pyomo.core.base.expr import identify_variables
# assuming model.objective is your Objective component
varList = list( identify_variables(model.objective.expr) )
firstDerivs = differentiate(model.objective.expr, wrt_list=varList)
# Note this calculates d^2/dx_i^2; if you want the full Hessian matrix
#   ( \delta^2/{\delta x_i \delta x_j} ) replace "wrt=v" with "wrt_list=varList"
secondDerivs = [ differentiate(firstDerivs[i], wrt=v) for i,v in enumerate(varList) ]
```

Of course, given that your expression is quadratic, symbolic and numeric differentiation will both give you the same answer.

Comment: this fails with an `invalid syntax` error unfortunately. Either my expression is too complicated for the parser or there's an issue with the variable names. Too bad, since it looked to be such an elegant solution

Comment: Could you give some more detail on the `invalid syntax` error?

Comment: `sympy.core.sympify.SympifyError: Sympify of expression 'could not parse` and then follows the expression string. So it's `sympy` that fails. I would parse the expression string but that's really long (almost 100k)

Comment: This could be an issue with the expression string being too long for sympy to parse. Can you share the expression generator and the index sets?

Comment: i'm marking this as the right answer. the parsing error was caused by one or more of the variables havind spaces inside them. pyomo had no issue with this, but sympy just didn't like it