# Computing numeric derivatives with pyomo

Tags: python-3.x, mathematical-optimization, pyomo

I need to repeatedly compute derivatives at a given point of nonlinear pyomo constraints. According to [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46570022/in-pyomo-how-can-one-extract-the-second-derivative-from-the-objective-function), there are basically two options: one symbolic approach (which uses sympy) and one numeric approach via  the NL file generated by Pyomo.

I have tried the symbolic approach which looks like:

```
def gradient(constr, variables):
    grad_num = np.array([value(partial) for partial in 
    differentiate(constr.body, wrt_list=variables)])
    if (not (is_leq_constr(constr))):
    grad_num = -grad_num
    return grad_num
```

In principle, this approach works. However, when dealing with larger problems, the function call takes very long and I would expect the numeric approach to be much faster.

Is this true? If so, can anyone help me, to "translate" the above function to the [gjh_asl_json](https://github.com/ghackebeil/gjh_asl_json) approach? I am grateful for any hint.

Comment: I've raised this as an [issue](https://github.com/Pyomo/pyomo/issues/665). It is a problem that I also run into more frequently now, and there is an ongoing project called Pynumero which should alleviate this issue, but that is a work in progress.